# Fermat's two square theorem, infinite descent last step

Tags: elementary-number-theory

On wikipedia there's what's supposed to be Euler's proof
[the proof in question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares#Euler.27s_proof_by_infinite_descent)

I get most of it, until the last sentences of the very last step.
So $p$ divides all the differences $a^{2n}-b^{2n}$ and the differences of the differences, et cetera, I get that.
Where does the $1^k, 2^k, 3^k....$ sequence come from, though? What does '$k$th difference' mean, and why does it equal  $k!$ ? (I thought $k$th would mean the $k^{k}-(k+1)^{k}$ difference but this is not the case, definitely not always).

Answer (score 2):

If one has a sequence $a_1$, $a_2,\ldots$, its differences are the elements
of the sequence $a_2-a_1$, $a_3-a_2,\ldots$. Formally we define
$$(\Delta a)_n=a_{n+1}-a_n.$$
We can iterate this construction; the second differences are the
differences of the differences: $a_3-2a_2+a_1$, $a_4-2a_3+a_2,\ldots$, that is
$$(\Delta^2a)_n=(\Delta a)_{n+1}-(\Delta a)_n=a_{n+2}-2a_{n+1}+a_n.$$
After $k$ iterations
$$(\Delta^ka)_n=\sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^{k-j}\binom{k}{j}a_{n+j}.$$

If we start with a polynomial sequence $a_n=f(n)$ where $f(x)=cx^m+$
lower terms, then $(\Delta a)_n=g(n)$ where $g$ is a polynomial
and $g(x)=mcx^{m-1}+$ lower terms. Iterating this, we find the
$m$-th difference is a constant: $(\Delta^ma)_n=m!c$.

Comment: I understand the definition now, thank you. But what are the 'lower terms' you mention?  
Would you mind showing how it's calculated on this particular example of $f(n)=n^k$?  
And are you sure the last line is right? Shouldn't it be $m$th difference of series of $a_n$ not $a_m$?

Comment: Lower terms: just terms with lower powers of $x$ (it's a polynomial).